# Dissolving adjacent polygons in R?

Tags: polygon, r, dissolve

I would like to dissolve only polygons that are adjacent to one another.  Ultimately I would like to start with a raster representing landscape patches and delineate the separate patches.  Here is my example, drawing from the raster::rasterToPolygons function in R:

```
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
set.seed(999)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
r <- r > 0.7
pol <- rasterToPolygons(r, fun=function(x){x==1})
pol.union <- rasterToPolygons(r, fun=function(x){x==1}, dissolve=T)

plot(r)
plot(pol, add=T)

plot(r)
plot(pol.union, add=T)
```

Without using the dissolve=T argument in rasterToPolygons, it returns a single polygon for each pixel where r==1 (189 polygons).  If I use dissolve=T it dissolves all of these into a single polygon.  What I want is something in between where each non-adjacent patch is it's own polygon (it would look like pol.union when plotted but would contain more than one polygon).  I believe what I want is to take pol and dissolve only the adjacent polygons.

I realize that this may require some input as to what is considered "adjacent" (i.e., whether only polygons sharing a boundary are considered adjacent or if polygons sharing a single point are considered adjacent).

Comment: See discussion here for doing this with sf https://github.com/edzer/sfr/issues/234  I think you can do this with spdep too but I haven't used